# Are Quartz Compositions portable to Linux?

Tags: development, unix, macos

I am interested in using Quartz Composer to make some visualization programs, that I want to run on a Raspbery Pi. 
My question is, is it possible to run something made in Quartz on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Quartz Compositions only run on Mac OS 10.4 and up.

There's a third-party tool, [Qtzweb](https://github.com/daeken/Qtzweb), which can translate a small subset of Quartz Composer patches into JavaScript WebGL code, which you could run in a browser on Linux.